# Do external C++ modules work with Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

If I were to include a module into my `.ino` file, would the compiler incorporate and compile it into the board as well? How would I go about doing it?

Example: `#include <array>`

Comment: The `array` class isn't external in any way, it's part of the standard library, and "modules" (which are a debated future extension to the C++ language) aren't involved at all. Would you like to clarify your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even if you get a specialized makefile for arduino to use C++, you don't get the beautiful STL. However, there is a person who recreated the [STL](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9Zobp2aWUKzb2xvZ0Y2VGd1RTQ) using inlined C++.

Other than that, you will need to remember that the makers of any external module may have to make it compatible for it to work. The include statement still works in arduino, just keep in mind that memory (both flash and RAM) is a big problem for big libraries on small systems like arduino.

EDIT:
I did some digging around with the builtin library and turns out, Arduino is C++ by default. However, the library has so many macros and is designed for maximum C compatibility that it's hard to write good C++.